# Selected correct text fields with ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, reference

I have 2 tables in my SQL Server, `tblClientData` and `tblDataRef`. 
`tblDataRef` is used as my reference table to populate the comboboxes in my .Net application. In my comboboxes I display text, and when saving the record, I save the ID. Here's an example of what the `tblDataRef` looks like...

**tblDataRef**

```
ID         Name
100        Accounting
101        Finance
102        Marketing
110        Supervisor
111        Shift Supervisor
112        Manager
113        VP
```

and my **tblClientData**

```
IDClient       Dept        Position       Salary        
177            101         112            100,000
454            102         113            350,000
```

What I'm trying to do is as an example:

```
Select * from TblClientData where IDClient = 177
```

I'll be populating a DataGridView with this data, so when I actually select all this data, I don't want to have ID's (101, 112, etc) but rather I'd like for it to say Marketing, Manger, etc. There's quite a few more fields in tblClientData as well as tblDataRef, they all work the same way (display text - saveID)

Is there a quick way to do this?

Hoping to achieve this on :

```
 IDClient   Dept       Position    Salary
 177        Finance    Manager     100,000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
SELECT IDClient,t4.FName,t4.LName,t2.Name Dept,t3.Name Position,Salary 
FROM TblClientData t1 
INNER JOIN tblDataRef t2 ON t1.Dept = t2.ID
INNER JOIN tblDataRef t3 ON t1.Position = t3.ID
INNER JOIN tblClientPer t4 ON t1.IDClient = t4.ClientNo 
WHERE  IDClient = 177
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks!

Comment: maybe you can also help me with this (without adding another questino) but what if I wanted to also get the Fname and Lname from tblClientPer and get it to show it with all the rest of the data

Comment: Ok nop, tell me what is relation of tblClientPer(columnNames) with above two tables

Comment: ClientNo in tblClientPer AND IdClient in tblClientData/TblDataRef

Comment: Updated as per given info.try it

Comment: @Bobski A couple of tips: Use aliases that make sense, e.g. `TblDataRef as Department`. `t2` doesn't mean anything. And use the aliases throughout the query, e.g. `where Client.ClientId = 177`. It makes it clearer and easier to maintain.